# Failed To Resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement the new Firestore database in a project that already uses Firebase features, including Realtime Database - which I want to "upgrade".

I'm working according to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) guide, but I'm getting stuck at compiling the Firestore library.

**This is my current project gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is my current app gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tal.wikirace"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    compile  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project works fine, but when I try to add this line:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
```

I get this message:

```
Failed To Resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2
```

I have updated `Android SDK Build-Tools`, `Google Play-Services` and `Support Repository`, but it didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're missing the google maven repo in your allprojects block:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Gradle 4.1 or later, you can simplify it:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

allprojects repositories is what's used to locate modules for your app.  In buildscript, it locates modules for gradle plugins only.

Also, you should make sure all of your Firebase modules have the same version.

Comment: @RunLoop It's in the current docs.  The embedded video hasn't been updated, but it will be. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Don't worry I could not install it anyway as it clashed with the version of Google Play used by the project. Upgrading that version caused other clashes and missing dependencies in a never ending mess. In the end I had to revert to the original state and remove firebase.

Comment: There should be no problems if all the Play and Firebase dependencies are at the same version.

Comment: Believe it or not, but this answer just served me for the second time!

Comment: It's useful for me !