# How to use FirebaseApp.initializeApp for FirebaseRemoteConfig

Tags: java, android, firebase, runtime-error, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to use FirebaseApp.initializeApp, but its not working. I have the right library, but I cannot use the JSON file to initialize the app

This is my code:

Imports

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings;
```

Variables

```
private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;

private String projectID;
private String apiKey;
private String appID;
```

How I initialize the app

```
public void Initialize() {
    FirebaseOptions mFirebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId(this.appID)
        .setApiKey(this.apiKey)
        .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.context, mFirebaseOptions, this.projectID);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
}
```

The app crashed on startup this is the logcat error:

```
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.makeroid.sanderjochems.FirebaseRemoteConfig, PID: 12566
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzby;
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.FirebaseRemoteConfiguration.<init>(FirebaseRemoteConfiguration.java:67)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at gnu.expr.PrimProcedure.apply(PrimProcedure.java:272)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at gnu.mapping.CallContext.runUntilDone(CallContext.java:234)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at gnu.mapping.CallContext.runUntilValue(CallContext.java:298)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at gnu.kawa.reflect.Invoke.applyN(Invoke.java:209)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at gnu.mapping.ProcedureN.apply2(ProcedureN.java:39)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.makeroid.sanderjochems.FirebaseRemoteConfig.Screen1.$define(Screen1.yail:10182)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Form.onCreateFinish(Form.java:389)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Form.onCreate(Form.java:336)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzby" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.makeroid.sanderjochems.FirebaseRemoteConfig-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.makeroid.sanderjochems.FirebaseRemoteConfig-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
12-04 22:11:42.217 12566 12566 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 25 more
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @DougStevenson I am using Firebase 11.0.4

Comment: Try upgrading to 11.6.2.  11.0.4 is pretty old.

Comment: Do you know where I can download that version of Firebase?

Comment: You don't download it - you reference it from google's maven repo now.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569165/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-firestore11-4-2/46569205#46569205

Comment: Are you building your app with [App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/)?  I see that name in the call stack.

Comment: Yes, but then with Makeroid its a clone of App Inventor @BobSnyder

I am creating new Components as Developer there

Answer (score 1):

Disable the `instant-run` while generating application and make sure you have added `google-services.json` file to your project.

Comment: I am not using android studio and I cant use the google-services.json file

Comment: what are you using?

Comment: I am compiling my app with Ant

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple problems.  I'll point out what appears to be one.

The documentation for [RemoteConfig.getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#getInstance()) notes that it expects the *default* `FirebaseApp` to be initialized:

> FirebaseRemoteConfig uses the default FirebaseApp...

Unlike some of the other Firebase APIs, there is no way to initialize `RemoteConfig` using a different `FirebaseApp`.

That means that when you initialze `FirebaseApp`, `projectID` must be "[DEFAULT]", which is available as constant [FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#DEFAULT_APP_NAME).

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.context, mFirebaseOptions, this.projectID);
```

Try setting `projectID` to "[DEFAULT]" (or the available constant) to see if the failure changes or is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am suggesting some solutions -

1. Build.gradle file

   ```
   multiDexEnabled true
   ```
2. Add this in your proguard-rules.pro file

   `-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }`