# No Cache available for version "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

While using google map activity in my android application I get this error.

**"Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0."**

**Project level** Gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application level** Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Check that you also have "Google Repository" installed under Extras in your Android SDK Manager.

Comment: yes, I've already installed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed To Resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569165/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-firestore11-4-2)

Comment: I had the same problem when tried to build the project from Android studio. Please try to build it from console. Then, when all of the dependencies are downloaded switch back to android studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, finally I got the answer,

I've turned on gradle offline mode that's why it could not find out cached files for that version play-service.

I turned it off (under File-Settings-Build,Execution,Deployment-Gradle) and again sync project and some files have been downloaded then it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include this *class path* inside project level *gradle*.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

As well as inside app level *build.gradle*.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Erro: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.